# Latexmk setting -pvc and -c in emacs

Tags: emacs, latexmk

I am using `emacs` on mac OS and I have the following setting about `.latexmkrc` and `init.el`. Now I want to use `-c` option to remove files such as `aux`. So I changed from `"latexmk -pvc %t"` to `"latexmk -pvc -c %t"`. It worked. But after the compile I changed `tex` file, this change does not reflect in pdf file automatically. How do I fix this issue? Or are there efficient way to deal with this issue?

`.latexmkrc`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$pdflatex         = 'lualatex -file-line-error -halt-on-error %O --shell-escape %S';
$biber            = 'biber --bblencoding=utf8 -u -U --output_safechars';
$pdf_mode         = 1;
$bibtex           = 'pbibtex';
$pvc_view_file_via_temporary = 0;
$max_repeat                  = 5;
$pdf_previewer    = "open -ga /Applications/Skim.app";
```

`init.el`

```
(use-package latex
  :ensure auctex
  :mode ("\\.tex\\'" . LaTeX-mode)
  :config
  (setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
                               (push
                                '("latexmk" "latexmk -pvc %t" TeX-run-TeX nil t
                  :help "Run Latexmk-LuaLaTeX")
                                TeX-command-list)))
  (add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq TeX-command-default "latexmk"))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-c` does a removal (clean-up) of aux files etc **instead** of a normal run.  (That's in the documentation.)  So the combination `-pvc -c` just does the clean-up and the `-pvc` option doesn't do anything.  If you want do to a clean up followed by a normal compilation, use the `-gg` option, i.e., do `latexmk -gg -pvc ...`.  See the documentation for details.

Comment: I tried ```latexmk -gg -pvc ...```. After a compilation, there exists ```aux``` and something in my folder. Does ```-gg``` mean a clean up but creating a new aux files?  If so, why this command is helpful?

Comment: Its main use is if you want to do a clean compilation without pre-existing aux files for some reason. Note that the clean up caused by `-gg` is **before** the compilation.  The compilation generates new aux files etc. If you want to remove the aux files **after** the compilation, you'll need to run `latexmk -c` separately.  In the current version of latexmk, there is no option to cause removal aux files after the compilation, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: I understand the system. Thank you so much.